# How to enter my customized winPE and not winRE in POST process when I press F11 key?

Tags: windows, post, winpe

I need a configuration that allows booting into a customized Windows Preinstallation Environment (WINPE) instead of Windows Recovery Environment (WINRE) when I continuously press the F11 key (set as the recovery mode entry key) right after the Power-On Self-Test (POST) during the initial booting of my PC.

I just tried GRUB to do that but not worked(huh).

Comment: usually that key is hard-coded in BIOS and you won't be able to change it's destination. Maybe you should have a look at partitionIDs and find a way to set your WinPE's ID to the WinRE ID. Keep in mind, that you won't be able to boot to WinRE then.
Another option: As WinRE is nothing else but a customized WinPE, you might want to edit it to fit your expectations.